# the same WSAPI v2.0 security key works in a REST client, but produces invalid key error when used with curl

Tags: curl, rally

In a browser's REST Client, when I post to this URL

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/HierarchicalRequirement/create?key=123abc

with this request body:

```
{
"HierarchicalRequirement": 
{"Name": "mystory"}
}
```

it works, but

```
curl -u 'user@co.com:password' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d  '{"HierarchicalRequirement": {"Name": "mystory"}}' https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/HierarchicalRequirement/create?key=123abc
```

produces an invalid key error:

```
{"CreateResult": {"_rallyAPIMajor": "2", "_rallyAPIMinor": "0", "Errors": ["Not authorized to perform action: Invalid key"], "Warnings": []}}
```

I thought initially that the security key expires (does it ever?) but reused it again successfully in the REST client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Authorization key is valid for as long as the HTTP session is valid. The difference between the browser REST client and your command-line curl is that the browser is automatically maintaining the HTTP session via a session cookie. Without session cookies, each curl request constitutes a new HTTP session.

You can tell curl to store a session cookie in order to persist the HTTP session. Here's how:

`$ curl -u "user@company.com:topsecret" https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/security/authorize -c cookie.txt`

Response:

```
{ "OperationResult" : { "Errors" : [  ],
      "SecurityToken" : "fb34ea43-21b9-314f-e23d-1c8ad281b42b",
      "Warnings" : [  ],
      "_rallyAPIMajor" : "2",
      "_rallyAPIMinor" : "0"
    } }
```

Note the session ID information in the cookie:

`$ more cookie.txt`

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

#HttpOnly_rally1.rallydev.com   FALSE   /       TRUE    0       JSESSIONID      qs-app-tutewruthe4p3favagatR4qakat.qs-app-02
#HttpOnly_.rally1.rallydev.com  TRUE    /       TRUE    0       ZSESSIONID      thUZExetAxAj6JaquStaZaPresPe8He3aPhawAb2pU
#HttpOnly_.rally1.rallydev.com  TRUE    /       TRUE    0       SUBBUCKETID     4343
```

Finally, issue the create command with curl, using the token you obtained via the authorize endpoint, and the `-b` flag for curl to specify the cookie file:

`$ curl -u 'user@company.com:topsecret' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d  '{"HierarchicalRequirement": {"Name": "mystory"}}' https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/HierarchicalRequirement/create?key=fb34ea43-21b9-314f-e23d-1c8ad281b42b -b cookie.txt`

Response:

```
{ "CreateResult" : { "Errors" : [  ],
      "Object" : {
          "CreationDate" : "2013-07-06T15:00:32.380Z",
          "LastUpdateDate" : "2013-07-06T15:00:32.437Z",
          "Name" : "mystory",
          "ObjectID" : 12345678920,
          "Project" : { "_rallyAPIMajor" : "2",
              "_rallyAPIMinor" : "0",
              "_ref" : "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/project/12345678911",
              "_refObjectName" : "My Project",
              "_type" : "Project"
            },
          "Rank" : 10433947185.0,
          "Subscription" : { "_rallyAPIMajor" : "2",
              "_rallyAPIMinor" : "0",
              "_ref" : "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/subscription/12345678912",
              "_refObjectName" : "My Subscription",
              "_type" : "Subscription"
            },
          "Workspace" : { "_rallyAPIMajor" : "2",
              "_rallyAPIMinor" : "0",
              "_ref" : "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/workspace/12345678913",
              "_refObjectName" : "My Workspace",
              "_type" : "Workspace"
            },
          "_CreatedAt" : "just now",
        },
      "Warnings" : [  ],
      "_rallyAPIMajor" : "2",
      "_rallyAPIMinor" : "0"
    } }
```

Comment: Thank you for a very detailed answer, it worked exactly as you described.