# How to update a defect using Rally WebServices API in PHP

Tags: php, web-services, rally

I am trying to update a Rally defect in PHP.  I have the query - auth - etc parts working. I can find the ObjectID of the defect to edit.  I am posting to the url outlined in another question.

Post using 'create' endpoint with the security token appended in the end. In this example 123456789 is the OID of the defect where Description field is being updated

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/defect/123456789?key=fbaa0c04-...
```

The problem is that the result of this POST is the original defect and the defect is not updated. I don't get an error message just no updates take effect. Am I misunderstanding the Post using 'create' endpoint?  this only occurs when the key is not supplied on the URL. It seems to act as a GET of the defect.

The problem is with the value of the key parameter.  The payload of this call must have only the object JSON. But I can't get past the key validation.

I make the call to get the security token twice to ensure that my curl session is valid and I get the same key. Which is correct. Then I immediately use that key and get an "Invalid Key" response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps below are from a browser REST client, and not specific to PHP.
The assumption is that the security key is already obtained.

To create a defect:

URL:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/Defect/create?key=f8e4afc5-....
```

Method: 
POST

Payload:

```
{
"Defect":{
"Name": "bad defect"
}
```

To update the same defect:

Browser maintains the session, and as long as the session is not terminated, the same security token can be used.

If the session was terminated ,e.g. due by the user or due to inactivity, a new token must be requested.
Below it is assumed that the same token is still valid.
Note that the payload has to include only the fields that are being updated, but "Defect" work item type must be specified also.

URL:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/defect/15297487557?key=f8e4afc5-....
```

Method: 
POST

Payload:

```
{"Defect":{
"Description":"pretty bad defect",
"State":"Open",
"Owner":"/user/12361716944"
}
}
```

The browser maintains the session automatically, and the Ruby, Java or .NET REST toolkits Rally supports also take care of that for the user, but with PHP you need to to do this in your code manually. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498650/the-same-wsapi-v2-0-security-key-works-in-a-rest-client-but-produces-invalid-ke) about a cURL example may help.

Comment: This suggestion does match the documentations use of the key as parameter and JSON object as payload. But, this yields an "Invalid Key" error. To test the auth key, I make the call to /security/authorize twice and compare - assuming that if the key is in session correctly I will get the same value on second call.  This works but can't get defect update to accept my key.

Comment: It looks like by the time you try update or create the session where you got the security token was already expired, and the token is no longer valid. Please see the last paragraph I added to the post above.

Comment: The session has not expired. To test that my security token was properly session based i make the call twice and compare values. If the same token is returned I immediately place the update that fails on Invalid Key.

Comment: Are you storing a session cookie in order to persist the HTTP session, similar to the cURL example? You may test the same endpoints with 1.43 of WS API, which does not require the security key.

Comment: This answer might prove helpful in the above regard for PHP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424714/how-to-maintain-session-in-curl-in-php

Comment: I switched to using version 1.43 to avoid the key as suggested by nickm. This is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Remove key= from the url & add the value to the header as zsessionid